# Pandas: Dataframe with updated, longer column

Tags: python, pandas

My script goes as it creates a dataframe with headers `Pass` and `Error`. It then reads all sources to fall, by default, under `Pass`. It then detects all errors which removes that source from `Pass` and notes it under `Error` column.

*creates DataFrame with `Pass`, `Error` headers*

```
    Pass     Error
```

*adds sources*

```
    Pass     Error  
0   source1  NaN  
1   source2  NaN
```

I then have 4 errors as `pd.Series(errors)` but only the first two errors are  displayed. How do I achieve my *expected*?

*actual*

```
    Pass     Error  
0   source1  source2err1  
1   NaN      source2err2
```

*expected*

```
    Pass     Error  
0   source1  source2err1  
1   NaN      source2err2  
2   NaN      source2err3  
3   NaN      source2err4
```

**UPDATE**

```
def update_df(file):
    errors = report_df[ERROR].dropna().tolist()
    sources = report_df[PASS].dropna().tolist()   
    new_errors = get_errors(file)
        if new_errors:  
            errors.extend(new_errors)  
            if file in sources:  
                sources.remove(file)  
    report_df[ERROR] = pd.Series(errors)  
    report_df[PASS] = pd.Series(sources)
```

Comment: What is your code for add `pd.Series(errors)` to `DataFrame` ? How data are aligned by `Pass` column?

Comment: what i did was `errors=report_df[ERROR].dropna().tolist()` *check for errors and update `errors` list* then put it back as `report_df[ERROR]=pd.Series(errors)`

Comment: There is different length of data, so it failed. Can you add your code? I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: yes, I have stumbled on that different length of data. is there a way i could adjust the number of rows to the column with the longest row index and populate everything else with `NaN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try create new `DataFrame` with `Series` like:

```
sources = list('xy')
errors = list('abcd')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pass': pd.Series(sources), 'Errors': pd.Series(errors)})
print (df)
  Pass Errors
0    x      a
1    y      b
2  NaN      c
3  NaN      d
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
sources = list('xy')
errors = list('abcd')
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(sources), pd.Series(errors)], keys=('Pass','Errors'), axis=1)
print (df)
  Pass Errors
0    x      a
1    y      b
2  NaN      c
3  NaN      d
```

Comment: i thought i could stray away from `pd.concat()` but nonetheless, it worked. Thanks a million!